# Javascript screen orientation on safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, screen-orientation

I'm trying to make a responsive web site and it is almost finished, but I need a hand.

I'm using this example to know the angle:

```
    angulo = screen.orientation || screen.mozOrientation || screen.msOrientation;
    
    Example angulo.angle
```

It returns 0, but it does not work with Safari, only with MSF and Chrome.
In Safari it shows:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'angulo.angle')
```

What can I do?

Comment: are you trying to figure out if a device is in portrait or landscape mode?

Comment: before `angulo =`, do `screen = screen || window;`

Answer (score 33):

If it's a case that you need the angle to determine whether your page is in portrait or landscape mode, then use the following:

```
document.addEventListener("orientationchange", updateOrientation);
```

You could also use `matchMedia`

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");

// If there are matches, we're in portrait
if(mql.matches) {  
    // Portrait orientation
} else {  
    // Landscape orientation
}

// Add a media query change listener
mql.addListener(function(m) {
    if(m.matches) {
        // Changed to portrait
    }
    else {
        // Changed to landscape
    }
});
```

OR you could use a `resize` event

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    // Get screen size (inner/outerWidth, inner/outerHeight)

}, false);
```

There are more hints in [David Walsh's handy article](https://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change) (but probably other examples too on SO)

Comment: Thank you very much, `window.matchMedia` saved me.

Comment: I would gladly accept it. But I didn't create the question. I just benefitted from your answer and upvoted you answer.

Comment: @SrAxi sorry, should have looked a bit closer. Glad it helped more than one :).  Thanks for the vote, and all the best ...

Comment: This may not work if inside an IFRAME. Meaning the `window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");` will be based on the ratio height and width of the IFRAME and not the screen. As so just usable of your in parent frame.

Comment: As of September 2022, this is the way for cross platform orientation detection. Until Safari supports the `change` event on `screen.orientation`. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Safari/Safari iOS (a.k.a. new IE6) is the not supporting the screen.orientation api. You have to use window.orientation instead (which is not a valid property)

exemple: http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-javascript-ios-orientation/

Comment: Which is a big shame, because (1) `window.orientation` is deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientation (2) You are NOT guaranteed to get the result you want. https://www.matthewgifford.com/2015/07/11/a-misconception-about-window-orientation/

Comment: If it's deprecated, how can I get the orientation after an orientation change on safari ios ?

Comment: Just because it's deprecated doesn't mean you can't use it. It just may be removed at some point.